# JPG images not appearing but WEBP images are

Tags: html, css, jpeg, webp

I'm trying to build a website with HTML. I'm using an img tag to display an image. When the src links to a WEBP file, it works fine. However, when I replace that WEBP with a JPG, it no longer works. Have tried .jpg and .jpeg extensions, as well as no extension. I know that the path is correct because WEBPs work fine. Any idea what the problem is? The image displayed instead is a standard broken image logo. Thanks.

Comment: You actually must have `.jpg` image, can't just rename link URL extension and expect it to work. **You must have exact file that you refer to**. Unless your server has some routing, then it's different question

Comment: share your code...